# length of continuously differentiable curves

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, curves

I saw that the length of a continuously differentiable curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\gamma(t) \neq 0$ is defined as $\int_a^b |\gamma^{'}(t)|dt$, as can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve#Lengths_of_curves .

I dont understand why does it really define length as we want it to be?
I hoped someone could explain the idea behind the definition and give some intuition.

Comment: The idea is that you can partition the domain into very small pieces and use lines to approximate the curve. The sum of the lengths is the "length" of the curve and taking limits formalizes it. MVT gives the connection to differentiation.

Comment: Do you like Euclidean distance? That's why we use that measurement for length. If we lived in a universe where waking from point a to point b was like walking around a city, straight line distances don't work, we'd use the Manhattan distance. Concretely speaking $\pi_e=3.14...$ and the Manhattan pi would be $\pi_m=4$

Comment: at "time" $t$ you are at $\gamma(t)$, at $t+\mathrm{d}t$ you are at $\gamma + \mathrm{d}t\gamma'(t)$. Now compute the distance covered between these two points for the infinitesimal length, and integrate to compute the total length

Comment: An informal interpretation: think of $\lvert{\gamma'(t)}\rvert$ as your speed at time $t$ as you move along the curve. The distance you travel is your speed multiplied the time traveled -- with changing speed this is formulated as exactly that integral.

Comment: you might start by asking, what should length intuitively be. Like, what is the length of a line segment, or of a polygonal path? then, approximate a curve by polygonal paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\gamma$ be the curve in question and partition $[a,b]$ as $a = t_0,...,t_k = b$. To determine $L(\gamma)$ the length of the curve $\gamma$ you approximate its length by the sum of the lengths of the $k$ different line segments joining $\gamma(t_i)$ and $\gamma(t_{i+1})$ with $i=0,...,k-1$.

With this in mind let

- $l(t)$ be the length of the curve from $\gamma(a)$ to $\gamma(a+t)$. In particular $l(a) = 0$ and $l(b) = L(\gamma).$
- $\Delta_i t = t_{i+1}-t_i$ be a small change in the variable $t$
- $\Delta_i l = l(t_{i+1})-l(t_i)$ the length of the curve $\gamma$ between $\gamma(t_{i+1})$ and $\gamma(t_i)$
- $\Delta_i \gamma = \gamma(t_{i+1})- \gamma(t_i)$ so that $\vert \Delta_i \gamma \vert $ is the length of the line segment joining $\gamma(t_i)$ and $\gamma(t_{i+1})$.

Intuitively as the partition gets finer and finer we have

$$ \Delta_i l \approx \vert \Delta_i \gamma \vert $$

Now multiply by $1 = \frac{\Delta_i t}{\Delta_i t}$ on the right hand side and sum over all the $i$ to find

$$ \sum_i \Delta_i l \approx \sum_{i} \left\vert \frac{\Delta_i \gamma}{\Delta_i t} \right\vert\Delta_i{t}.$$

On the left you find $l(b) = L(\gamma)$ and the right side intuitively converges to the $\int_a^b \vert \gamma'(t)\vert dt$ when the partition gets finer and finer.

To make this into a rigorous proof all you need to do is to show that

$$ \frac{dl}{dt} = \vert \gamma'(t)\vert$$

since you'll have
$$ L(\gamma) = l(b) - l(a) = \int_{a}^b \frac{dl}{dt} dt = \int_a^b \vert \gamma'(t)\vert dt.$$

Comment: @MCL I've edited this answer since it contained a huge mistake. Namely the fact that I used the M.V.T. for $\gamma$ as if it were a real valued function which it obviously isn't (unless $n= 1$ of course). This answer avoids that issue entirely.